# Particles system falls down

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a fps with a gun and it has a particles system as effect for the gun shot. The problem is that the effect multiply and falls down. I don't know if I can control this from the effect inspector or the script of spawning projectiles

[image]

[image]
[image]

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpawnProjectiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject firePoint;
    public List<GameObject> vfx = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject effectToSpawn;
    public Button button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        effectToSpawn = vfx[0];
        button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        
    }
    void SpawnVFX ()
    {
        GameObject vfx;
        if(firePoint != null)
        {
            vfx = Instantiate(effectToSpawn, firePoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 


        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("NoFirePoint");
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick()
    {

        SpawnVFX();


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show whats under the emission tab, https://i.imgur.com/jX0hUGu.png . I would assume based on that script that a new particle system is being created from a prefab each time you fire (without destroying previous particle systems), and that your particle system might have some emission over time.

I would recommend having a single particle system, and calling `myParticleSystem.Emit(/* Number of particles to spawn*/)` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html whenever you fire.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ga7OFkl @RishaanGupta